# "Script Error Displaying unprocessed Data

Tags: json, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am currently  following the mulesoft fundamentals 4 module 5. as i have been following  the guide i should be able to  Make requests to the API proxy from Exchange. However, every-time i click send i get an Error; Script error. Displaying unprocessed data"

The Error message Below: 
Script error. Displaying unprocessed data.
''''''

[The image displays the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZk1C.png)

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the server is unreachable or bad gateway (502).Make sure the implementation URL which you provide to create proxy is working.In my case I have used https instead of http.

[image: Please Find the image to know where implementation URL to be given]